# How to ignore a folder and its subfolders in gitignore?

Tags: git

I want to ignore the folder **target** of my Spring project. I set this in the `.gitignore` file but I still see some target folder path in the SmartGit panel :

```
target/
```

So what is wrong ?

Comment: If that folder was already versioned, you must delete it from git: `git rm -rf target`

Comment: You'd want to use the `--cached` option to `git rm` to only delete it from the index, keeping your working copy.

Comment: after running `git rm -rf target --cached` the `target` foldern is still seen in the panel !